# CSS Bug with inline ul li in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

I've got a little issue with a inline menu, bug only appears in ie7. The only menu li that has another menu underneath it, is not inline with the rest, the rest seem to appear pushed down.

HTML

```
<div id="topnav">
<ul id="jsddm">
<li id="">
<a id="" href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li id="">
<a href="/about.aspx">About</a>
<ul style="visibility: hidden;">
<li>
<a href="/about/board.aspx">Board</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/about/contact.aspx">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/practices.aspx">Practices</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/how-we-work.aspx">How we work</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/patients.aspx">Patients</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/news-links.aspx">News &amp; Links</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/link.aspx">Link</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #jsddm
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#jsddm li
{   
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

*+html #jsddm li { display:inline }
* html #jsddm li { display:inline }

#jsddm ul li
{   
    display: block;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial;
}

#jsddm li ul
{   
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-top: 0px solid white;
    *margin: 0 0 0 -50px; /* IE 7 and below */
     /* margin: 0 0 0 -50px\9; IE 8 and below */
}

#jsddm ul li ul li
{           
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial
}

#jsddm li a
{
    display: block;
    background: #009EE0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 0px solid white;
    width: 70px;
    color: #EAFFED;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}

#jsddm li a:hover
{   background: #1A4473}

#jsddm li ul li
{   
    float: none;
    *margin: -2px 0 0 0;
    *padding:0;
}

+html #jsddm li ul li {  }

#jsddm li ul li a
{
    width: auto;
    background: #009EE0
    font-weight: bold;
}

#jsddm li ul li a:hover
{   background: #0E559C }
```

It uses a jquery function to display the dropdownmenu but it does'nt effect the static html/css.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support `inline-block`. Try to float the elements in it - http://jsfiddle.net/SsDnd/1/

```
#jsddm li
{   
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    *float: left;
}
```

Comment: i'm overiding it for ie7 with:

*+html #jsddm li { display:inline; }
* html #jsddm li { display:inline; }

straight after #jsddm li

Comment: try to `float` instead of `inline`

Comment: thanks, I already had a rule in just for the li in ie7 when I was testing things out, was just wondering if there was some special hack somebody had come up with so you would'nt have to fall back to *float:left. I've gone with that for now. cheers